# How to fetch only the url links from the string in python?

Tags: python, regex, string

How do I fetch only the links from my file shown below:

```
Jun 15 16:26:21 dnsmasq[1979]: query[A] fd-geoycpi-uno.gycpi.b.yahoodns.net from 192.168.1.33 

Jun 15 16:26:30 dnsmasq[1979]: query[A] armdl.adobe.com from 192.168.1.24

Jun 15 16:26:32 dnsmasq[1979]: query[A] updates.installshield.com from 192.168.1.118
```

Note: the links may or may not start with "www." or end with ".com" (example: armdl.adobe.com, fd-geoycpi-uno.gycpi.b.yahoodns.net) but the "query[A]" before the link and "from" after the link remains same for every string. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe [`s.split()[5]`](http://rextester.com/DCLK45366)? Well, *the "query[A]" before the link and "from" after the link remains same for every string* means you just want to extract a string between two strings, right? Closing as a dupe.

Comment: s.split()[5] should work.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes exactly I want to extract the string between the given claws...

Comment: I have found 2 SO threads that answer your question. If you decide to use  a regex, do not forget to escape `[` in the pattern to match a literal `[`.

Comment: Thank you @WiktorStribiżew it worked